# Как "java.exe" находит файл с нужным классом при запуске?

Tags: java

Известно, что запуск java программ (скомпилированных .class файлов) происходит с помощью вызова:

> java ИмяКласса

но как JVM находит файл в котором реализован данный класс?
Конечно, если следовать рекомендациям, то класс Main будет в файле Main.class, но эту рекомендацию можно нарушить, сделать класс Main в файле Something.class и все равно java сможет запустить такой проект.

Неужели java просматривает все файлы в области видимости своего окружения, вытаскивая названия всех реализованных классов? Таких же .class файлов могут быть тысячи?
Или есть какая то хитрость?

Comment: *но эту рекомендацию можно нарушить* - для `public` классов нельзя

Comment: Если нарушить, то не запустится, и, может, даже не скомпилируется.

Comment: мы ж вроде пишем в файле с расширением .java затем компилируется это всё в разширение .class где прописываются все инстроикции в байт-коде и происходит  прочая магия, как-то так

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, вопрос не имеет смысла. Когда я проводил эксперименты, то ошибся и вот это заявление:

> но эту рекомендацию можно нарушить, сделать класс Main в файле
> Something.class

на самом деле ошибочно. То есть, для публичных классов (каковым должен являться стартовый класс) так делать нельзя, класс Main может быть описан только в файле Main.java